# How to set value of object with another same value inside of the same object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Can i use a value of object/array to define another object/array value directly inside of it?

DESCRIPTION

I know that's not the proper way to do this but i was trying different ways and was frustrating...

THE CODE I'VE TRIED:

```
$object= (object)array(
    'akey'=>'value',
    'anotherkey'=>'anothervalue',
    'the_key_of_interested_special_value'=>$this->data_evento
);
var_dump($object);
```

And it throws me a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context on line 4

I don't want to use an external variable/array/object and/or functions outside of the array/object definiton.

I already know i can do something like this:

```
$object= (object)array(
    'akey'=>'value',
    'anotherkey'=>'anothervalue'
);
$object->the_key_of_interested_special_value = $object->akey.'_correct';

var_dump($object);

var_dump($object);
```

And the result would be (that's the result id'like to obtain without external definitons):

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["akey"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["anotherkey"]=>
  string(12) "anothervalue"
  ["the_key_of_interested_special_value"]=>
  string(17) "value_correct"
}
```

Comment: are you thinking that `$this` refers to `$object`?

Comment: I don't think that a "recursive" object assignment inside of an object will work.

Comment: @Ghost yes I'd like to have a reference to the object so i can reach my goal! :D

Comment: @pbaldauf This is my first question on Stackoverflow because i always find the answer here but i think this time i've really done an hard question :)

I think thai you're right... but i'd like to be sure about this.

Comment: @user3281273 not possible, even inside classes, declaration of properties should be constant and doesn't rely on run time values

Comment: @Ghost OK. So mission impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this` only inside an object context. What you do is

1. Create an array
2. convert it to an object

*The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object)."* 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Can you give me a php-snippet?